# JSF(Primefaces) ajax update of several elements by ID's

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

One more question concerning JSF.Particularly, Primefaces.
Have following problem with ajax update of elements by id's at same time.
If elements on page goes one by one ,that ajax update performs ok:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{showProducts.inCart}" var="cart">
 <td><p:spinner min="0" value="#{cart.count}" immediate="true">
 <p:ajax process="@this" update="count,subTotal"/></p:spinner></td>         
 <td><h:outputText value="#{cart.totalPrice}" id="count"/></td>
 <h:outputText value="#{showProducts.subTotal}" id="subTotal"/>      
</ui:repeat>
```

Here element with id "count" goes first,then element with id "subtotal" goes second.
In case,elements on page are not strictly one by one,that second element with "subtotal" id is not updated:

```
    <ui:repeat value="#{showProducts.inCart}" var="cart">
      <td><p:spinner min="0" value="#{cart.count}" immediate="true">
<p:ajax process="@this" update="count,subTotal"/></p:spinner></td>         
      <td><h:outputText value="#{cart.totalPrice}" id="count"/></td>
      <td><h:outputText value="#{cart.place}" /></td>
    </ui:repeat>
    <h:outputText value="#{showProducts.subTotal}" id="subTotal"/>
```

Is it normal behaviour or I miss some parameters?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

If the to-be-updated component is not inside the same [`NamingContainer`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/NamingContainer.html) component (`ui:repeat`, `h:form`, `h:dataTable`, etc), then you need to specify the "absolute" client ID. Prefix with `:` (the default `NamingContainer` separator character) to start from root.

```
<p:ajax process="@this" update="count :subTotal"/>
```

To be sure, check the client ID of the `subTotal` component in the generated HTML for the actual value. If it's inside for example a `h:form` as well, then it's prefixed with its client ID as well and you would need to fix it accordingly.

```
<p:ajax process="@this" update="count :formId:subTotal"/>
```

Space separation of IDs is more recommended as `<f:ajax>` doesn't support comma separation and starters would otherwise get confused.

Comment: I'm getting `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: master` with an other situation. The `p:ajax update=":master"` is in a `ui:include` which is included within the `p:panelGrid id="master"` tag.

Comment: I think I better make a new post?

Comment: Your context is unclear. Better advance to https://stackoverflow.com/q/8634156

Comment: I fixed it already by avoiding `:master:` in front of my ids all together. :-)