# p:commandbutton update does not work

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, commandbutton

I have searched through forums and am aware of how id-generation of HTML-DOM-Elements work with NamingContainers and without them. Nonetheless, in this code i try to put a commandbutton in one side of the page, that should trigger an update of the other side of the page.

The 'viewWorkbenchButton' fires its action properly and the backend-data is fine. But :wbManageForm:wbMgmtPanel is not updated.

```
<ui:composition xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<f:view>
    <p:panel id="dataGridPanel">
        <p:panelGrid id="dataGridPanelGrid" styleClass="pGrid" columns="2"
            columnClasses="alignTop, alignTop">
            <p:column>
                <h:form id="wbSelectForm">
                    <p:panel styleClass="noBorderPanel">
                        <p:dataTable var="workbench"
                            value="#{WorkbenchControllerBean.myWorkbenches}"
                            paginator="#{WorkbenchControllerBean.myWorkbenches.size() > 10}"
                            rows="10"
                            paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}">
                            <f:facet name="header">  
                                    My Workbenches  
                                </f:facet>

                            <p:column headerText="Id" sortBy="#{workbench.workbenchId}">
                                <h:outputText value="#{workbench.workbenchId}" />
                            </p:column>

                            <p:column headerText="Name" sortBy="#{workbench.name}">
                                <h:outputText value="#{workbench.name}" />
                            </p:column>

                            <p:column headerText="Actions">
                                <p:commandButton id="viewWorkbenchButton" icon="ui-icon-show"
                                    title="View Workbench" update=":wbManageForm:wbMgmtPanel"
                                    actionListener="#{WorkbenchControllerBean.viewWorkbench(workbench)}">
                                </p:commandButton>

                            </p:column>
                        </p:dataTable>
                    </p:panel>
                </h:form>
            </p:column>

            <p:column>
                <h:form id="wbManageForm">
                    <p:panel id="wbMgmtPanel" styleClass="noBorderPanel">
                        <h:outputText id="tabText" value="Active Wb: #{WorkbenchControllerBean.number}" />
                        <p:tabView id="tabView">
                        ....
                        </p:tabView>

                    </p:panel>
                </h:form>
            </p:column>
        </p:panelGrid>
    </p:panel>
</f:view>
```

I already tried to update different components (`:wbManageForm`, `:wbManageForm:tabText`, `:wbManageForm:tabView:treetable`) but none of them was updated...

I am using Primefaces 3.5.

What am i missing here? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: What's the purpose of having two forms ? You could have just one, and update it with `@form`. Is your `ui:composition` inside a form too ?

Comment: Have you tried to update `@all`? Also, take a look in this answer of BalusC: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474789/jsfprimefaces-ajax-update-of-several-elements-by-ids

Comment: I tried everything but it still does not work. I minimized my code to better show the problem and asked again here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21044983/primefaces-commandbutton-update-does-not-work

Answer (score -1):

Try using `action` instead of `actionListener`. Also, update only the `wbmanageForm`. If that doesn't work, try updating the component with your bean method.

You can do that by adding this to the end of your method: `RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("wbManageForm");`

Comment: I tried everything but it still does not work. I minimized my code to better show the problem and asked again here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21044983/primefaces-commandbutton-update-does-not-work