# PrimeFaces commandButton 'Update' property doesn't work

Tags: jsf, mobile, primefaces, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have created a mobile web page using `PrimeFaces Mobile`. I am using PrimeFaces-4.0 and primefaces-mobile-0.9.4. Everything looks fine except that "`update`" property of `p:commandButton` does not work.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
  xmlns:pm="http://primefaces.org/mobile">
<f:view contentType="text/html" renderKitId="PRIMEFACES_MOBILE">
    <pm:page title="PrimeFaces Mobile" id="pm1">
        <pm:view id="viewA">
            <pm:header title="A"/>
            <pm:content>
                <h:form id="f1">
                    <p:inputText value="#{mobileBean.title}"/>
                    <p:commandButton value="Update" update=":formB:display" />
                </h:form>
            </pm:content>
        </pm:view>
        <pm:view id="viewB">
            <pm:header title="B"/>
            <pm:content>
                <h:form id="formB">
                    <h:outputText id="display" value="#{mobileBean.title}"/>
                </h:form>
            </pm:content>
        </pm:view>
    </pm:page>
</f:view>
```

I have tried also '`update="@([id$=display])"` ' as suggested here [primefaces commandbutton update does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21044983/primefaces-commandbutton-update-does-not-work) but nothing changes. Can anyone help please?

Comment: Use `h:head` and `h:body` elements inmediately after `html`. Later on, you can wrap `f:view` in your body.

Comment: Thanks for answering but nothing changed from this, just tried.